# AWS S3 object create event gives me _TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS_xxx file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am using `s3:ObjectCreated` event. File is dropped by sftp. Problem is that sometimes when a file is dropped, I would receive two events: one with _TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS_file-name as the name, and one with the original file-name. Why am I getting *TRANSFER_IN_PROGRESS* event and is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Step #11 here: [Transferring files using a client - AWS Transfer Family](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/transfer-file.html#winscp):

> Choose Disable for the Enable transfer resume/transfer to temporary filename for option.

Without this, the transfer process might be using a client that creates temporary files. If so, disable this option as shown in the instructions for WinSCP.

Comment: Oh so this is a feature from the client? Am not sure at the moment if WinSCP is used by our partner, but this looks right. Thx.